# Why is $C^{1}([a,b],||\cdot||_{\infty})$ dense in $C([a,b],||\cdot||_{\infty})$?

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces, normed-spaces

Let $C([a,b],||\cdot||_{\infty})$ be the space of continuous functions from $[a,b]$ to $\mathbb{K}$, where $\mathbb{K}\in\{\mathbb{R},\mathbb{C}\}$. I know that $C([a,b],||\cdot||_{\infty})$ is a Banach space.

It is easy to see that the same is ***not*** true for $C^{1}([a,b],||\cdot||_{\infty})$, the subspace of continuously differentiable functions. My guess is that $C^{1}([a,b],||\cdot||_{\infty})$ is actually ***dense*** in $C([a,b],||\cdot||_{\infty})$, but I have no idea how to prove that.

Can anybody help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This isn't meaningfully different from Mike F's answer, I just wanted to write out some details since there is a simple probabilistic answer to this question that only uses very basic probability and real analysis.

To avoid messy notation, I'll just take $a=0$ and $b=1$. This is without loss of generality by composing with a linear transformation. The claim is that polynomials are dense in $C[0,1]$. Fix $f \in C[0,1]$; we want to show that

$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}\sup_{x \in [0,1]}\left|f(x) - \sum_{m=0}^n \binom{n}{m}x^m(1-x)^{n-m}f(m/n)\right| =0.
$$
These are called [Bernstein polynomials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernstein_polynomial). For some intuition about what's going on here, let's suppose that $X_i$ are i.i.d. Bernoulli$(x)$ random variables (i.e. $P(X_i = 1) = x, P(X_i=0)=1-x$). Then for

$$
S_n = \sum_{i=1}^n X_i,
$$
we have
$$
P(S_n = m) = \binom{n}{m}x^m (1-x)^{n-m} \\
$$
$$
\mathbb{E}[S_n/n] = x
$$
and

$$
\mathbb{E}[f(S_n/n)] = \sum_{m=0}^n \binom{n}{m}x^m(1-x)^{n-m}f(m/n)
$$

Fix $\epsilon>0$. Since $f$ is uniformly continuous, we can fix a $\delta>0$ so that $|f(x)-f(y)|<\epsilon$ whenever $|x-y|<\delta$.
By [Chebychev's inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chebyshev%27s_inequality)
$$
\mathbb{P}\left(|S_n/n - x|>\delta\right) \leq \frac{Var(S_n/n)}{\delta^2} = \frac{x(1-x)}{n \delta^2} \leq \frac{1}{4n \delta^2}.
$$
By [Jensen's inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jensen%27s_inequality), for each $x$ we have
$$
\left|\sum_{m=0}^n \binom{n}{m}x^m(1-x)^{n-m}f(m/n) - f(x)\right| = \\
|\mathbb{E}[f(S_n/n)] - f(x)| \leq \mathbb{E}|f(S_n/n)-f(x)| \leq \epsilon + 2\|f\|_\infty\mathbb{P}(|S_n/n-x|>\delta) \\\leq \epsilon + \frac{\|f\|_\infty}{2n \delta^2}.
$$
Send $n \to \infty$ and then $\epsilon \to 0$ to obtain the result.

Answer (score 2):

You are correct that $C^1([a,b])$ is dense in $C([a,b])$ with respect to the uniform norm. There are a few ways to prove this, depending what is in your toolkit. One way would be to invoke the Weirstrass polynomial approximation theorem. Another would be to use convolution with a smooth approximation to the delta function to smooth out a given continuous function without changing it much.

Note that, while it is true that $C^1([a,b])$ is not a Banach space for $\|\cdot\|_\infty$, it *is* a Banach space with respect to other norms, such as $\|f\| := \|f\|_\infty + \|f'\|_\infty$.

Comment: What would be the simplest way to prove it? For someone with little to no background in functional analysis?

Comment: A pretty elementary proof might look something like this: use the fact that every continuous function on a compact interval is uniformly continuous to show that every continuous function can be uniformly approximated by a [piecewise linear function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Piecewise_linear_function). Then show that each piecewise linear function can be uniformly approximated by a $C^1$ function by using some explicit construction to "round off" the jagged bits of the graph.

Comment: You can also use Fourier series, as was mentioned in another answer (which got deleted). The Fourier series of a continuous function may not converge uniformly to the function, but [Fejér's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fej%C3%A9r%27s_theorem) fixes this problem by taking Cesaro averages.

Comment: I know nothing about Fejér or Cesaro. There must be a simple example, but I am not coming up with it...

Comment: If you just want an example, try showing that $f_n(x):=\sqrt{\frac{1}{n}+x^2}$ converges uniformly to $f(x)=|x|$ on $[-1,1]$ as $n \to \infty$.

Comment: @TheThinWhistler Proving it via convolution with a smooth function doesn't really require any functional analysis or heavy machinery and is a cool and important technique.

Comment: @operatorerror it does require a little care though since one needs to extend the function continuously to $\mathbb{R}$ or else the uniform convergence will break down at the boundary points. It's clear that that's possible, but if one wants to be rigorous, it is tedious.

Comment: That's a fair point, I still think it's worth doing at least once. I remember finding it a bit strange I learned it after Stone-Weirstrass.